# How can i add sub menu under custom top menu in QGIS using python

Tags: qgis, python

I have added "My Tools" Menu on top. Now i am clicking on "Plugin" then selecting QGIS Plugin bulider. Here in the menu field a drop down list is coming. How can i add "My tools" in this drop down list.[image]